# implementing a ios chat (like whatsapp): websocket?

Tags: ios, websocket, chat

I am trying to implement a chat service in ios. 
My question is: how  services (like whatsApp)  work?

I found a tutorial ([here](http://www.elabs.se/blog/66-using-websockets-in-native-ios-and-android-apps)) about how use websockets. Is it  right direction? 
In that case the chat only alive when the app is running.

Anyone have experinces on this ?

Answer (score 2):

Tutorial looks really nice, would say good direction.
If you want to implement socket in background too you need to look at background modes.

http://www.raywenderlich.com/29948/backgrounding-for-ios

In short if you open socket, you mark it as VOIP one, which will keep it opened even when in background.

Comment: Tx! The use of labels to mark could give problem in the apple approval process?

Comment: Well if your app is VOIP (well chat) it should be ok.
You want to get notified if somone sends you message and app is in bg ? Guess you could also try apple push notifications.

Comment: Are you saying to use Push notifications in addition to the websocket or using push as chat service and notification as well (avoiding to use websocket)?

Comment: While the app is in foreground you can use web socket, if app goes to the background you can receive push notifications. 
Otherwise background mode and keeping connection to server alive, or checks every x seconds.

Comment: Marking chat as VOIP one, allows to recive messages in background (although without notification)?

Comment: Well marking as VOIP allows you to keep connection alive while app is in bg, Apple push notifications allows you to recieve some text, while app is in bg. Have a look:
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iphone/conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/BackgroundExecution/BackgroundExecution.html

https://developer.apple.com/library/IOs/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Chapters/ApplePushService.html